# r shiny reactive gtsummary table

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, gtsummary, gt

After I fixed the rendering problem of {gtsummary} with your help: [How to use {gtsummary} package in r shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197029/how-to-use-gtsummary-package-in-r-shiny-app) !thanks to stefan again,
I try to construct reactivity in my app.
After construction of the summary table with {gtsummary} I would like to pass the y variable from a select input field to change the summary table.
I get this error: no applicable method for 'as_factor' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
That exceeds my limits. Can someone please help?
My Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)
# make dataset with a few variables to summarize
iris2 <- iris %>% select(Sepal.Length,  Sepal.Width, Species)

# summarize the data with our package
table1 <- tbl_summary(iris2) %>% as_gt()
table1

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             # Select variable for y-axis
             selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                         label = "Y-axis:", 
                         choices = names(iris2),
                         selected = "Sepal.Length"),
             gt_output('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    varY <- reactive({input$y})
    
    output$table <- render_gt({
      table1 <- tbl_summary(iris2[, varY()]) %>% as_gt() 
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `tbl_summary` expects a dataframe as its first argument, while your are passing a numeric vector `iris2[, varY()]`. If I got you right you want to select column `varY()` which could be achieved by:

```
table1 <- tbl_summary(select(iris2, all_of(varY()))) %>% as_gt()
```

Comment: Thank you stefan once again. Exactly what I needed!